# Wordpress blog assign unqiue body class

Tags: blog, body-class

I am using a function to change the body class depending on whether the user is on the home or sub page.

Currently everything is working as it should, the homepage is showing the home background and all the sub pages are showing the sub background except for the blog page, even the blog detail and categories page are showing the sub background but not the blog page itself.

My front page is a static page and the posts page is a page called blog.

I've included the function below - if anyone could help me get this fixed it would be great. Thanks for any help in advance.

**BODY CLASS FUNCTION**

```
function custom_body_class ($classes) {
// add 'class-name' to the $classes array
if( !is_front_page() && is_home() ) $classes[] = 'sub';
// return the $classes array
return $classes;}add_filter('body_class','custom_body_class');
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you've got !is_front_page() twice, but you just need to remove && !is_home(), because that's the blog page.

Answer (score 1):

Blog page (aka posts page) corresponds to `is_home()` conditional, which you are excluding.

`is_home()` is *often* at site root, but blog page configured to be elsewhere is exactly the case when it isn't.

Comment: That's not how I understood the question: "**but not** the blog page itself".

Comment: @Rarst thanks for the help. I've tried what you suggested and now the blog page is the only one of the sub pages displaying the sub background. Any ideas of how to solve this? I've updated the code in my original post.

Comment: As per comments above it's not clear what you want to achieve so it's hard to say how to solve it.

Comment: @Rarst I want to have a body class of 'sub' added to all sub pages (including the blog). The code I've included in the post above is only showing the sub background on the blog page and not on the other sub pages i.e. about us, contact us etc.